# bash: /home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin: Is a directory

Tags: bash, directory, environment-variables, path, hadoop

I am in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Based on [how to set a Hadoop cluster](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/) I am executing this:

```
# Add Hadoop bin and sbin directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin;$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

where I know that *bin* and *sbin* both lie in the same directory. However I am getting this:

```
bash: /home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin: Is a directory
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement has a semicolon where it should have a colon:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin;$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

versus

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

A semicolon `;` separates *statements*, not parts of a `PATH`.

The first time you ran the command, it added `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` to your `PATH` (which is okay). But it did not add `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin`.  You could simply edit the command in bash and resubmit it -- getting two copies of the `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`, which *works* but is wasteful.

Comment: Hmm I see...so now I just execute the correct command and it will overwrite the previous export? Or do I have to undo it in some way?? Now it has this value: "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hduser/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin". If you do not know, inform me to make a new question. Can you please say how to edit? Or point me to a link?

Comment: To edit in bash, I'd just press the up-cursor key or control/P and use left/right cursor key to move to the `;` character, then backspace (to delete it), and type `:` to insert it -- then enter...

Comment: Thanks, but it's still unclear to me, so I made a new question (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257895/how-to-edit-path), which I link here for the future readers..